# how to format the string in javascript using regular expression

Tags: javascript, html, regex

this is my string I get from database

```
var str=" The requirements of this chapter apply to the following:(1) New 
buildings or portions thereof used as health care occupancies (see 1.4.1)(2) 
Additions made to, or usedas, a health care occupancy (see 4.6.6 and 18.1.1.4)(2)
and test.Exception: Exception no 1  The requirement of 18.1.1.1.1 shall not apply
to additions classified as occupancies other than health care that are separated
from the health care occupancy in accordance with 18.1.2.1(2) and conform to the
requirements for the specific occupancy in accordance with Chapters 12 through 17
and Chapters 20 through 42, as appropriate.(3) Alterations, modernizations, or  
renovations of existing health care occupancies (see 4.6.7 and 18.1.1.4)(1)(4)
Existing buildings or portions thereof upon change of occupancy to a health care 
occupancy (see 4.6.11)Exception *: Facilities where the authority having 
jurisdiction has determined equivalent safety has been provided in accordance 
with Section 1.5."
```

I have used the following condition

```
str = str.replace(/(\s\(\d+\)|exception\s*\:*)/gi, "<br /><br />$1&nbsp");
```

from which I get:

```
The requirements of this chapter apply to the following:

(1) New buildings or portions thereof used as health care occupancies (see 1.4.1)

(2) Additions made to, or usedas, a health care occupancy (see 4.6.6 and 18.1.1.4)

(2) and test.

Exception: 

Exception no 1  The requirement of 18.1.1.1.1 shall not apply to additions classified as occupancies other than health care that are separated from the health care occupancy in accordance with 18.1.2.1(2) and conform to the requirements for the specific occupancy in accordance with Chapters 12 through 17 and Chapters 20 through 42, as appropriate.

(3) Alterations, modernizations, or renovations of existing health care occupancies (see 4.6.7 and 18.1.1.4)

(1)

(4) Existing buildings or portions thereof upon change of occupancy to a health care occupancy (see 4.6.11)

Exception *: Facilities where the authority having jurisdiction has determined equivalent safety has been provided in accordance with Section 1.5.
```

but my desired output is

```
The requirements of this chapter apply to the following:

(1) New buildings or portions thereof used as health care occupancies (see 1.4.1)

(2) Additions made to, or usedas, a health care occupancy (see 4.6.6 and 18.1.1.4)(2) and test.

Exception: Exception no 1  The requirement of 18.1.1.1.1 shall not apply to additions classified as occupancies other than health care that are separated from the health care occupancy in accordance with 18.1.2.1(2) and conform to the requirements for the specific occupancy in accordance with Chapters 12 through 17 and Chapters 20 through 42, as appropriate.

(3) Alterations, modernizations, or renovations of existing health care occupancies (see 4.6.7 and 18.1.1.4)(1)

(4) Existing buildings or portions thereof upon change of occupancy to a health care occupancy (see 4.6.11)

Exception *: Facilities where the authority having jurisdiction has determined equivalent safety has been provided in accordance with Section 1.5.
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: I think it would be better if you could show what part of this question you are struggling with after working on it yourself.

Comment: Is what you get wrong or something?

Comment: You've asked 16 questions. It's time to put a little more effort into properly formatting your post.

Comment: Please explain in words what you want the regex to do.  The examples by themselves are not clear enough.

Comment: you can see there that when it get (0 to 9) or "exception" it break to the new line. but there is also the (0-9) and "exception" word in the middle of the sentence which does not need to break the line..but my regex is simply breaking it to the new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already hard to "count" inside a regex, but what you're asking cannot be done with one. The regex doesn't have any memory of what it's catched before, so in the case of the second `(2)`, you won't have any tool to know it's already been matched.

Now, here comes an interesting tool of the replace function. You can specify a callback function instead here you can do a little bit of checking. The callback arguments will be:
1) The whole matched string
2) The capturing groups (so 0 to n arguments)
3) The position of the match
4) The initial string

So basically, you can for example capture the number you see and if you already saw them, do nothing (return the same string, ie, arguments[0]), and other things to help you...